# Unable to locate package qt5-default in LXD container

Tags: apt, qt, lxd

I am trying to install Qt in a LXD container but the [qt5-default](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/qt5-default) seems to be missing.
The LXD container is Ubuntu 18.04 based and I already installed the rest of the packages.
Any ideeas?
Thank you.

Host: Ubuntu 16.04, AMD64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package is available. Compare with the following steps.

```
$ lxc launch ubuntu:18.04 bionic
Creating bionic
Starting bionic

$ lxc exec bionic bash

root@bionic:~# apt update

root@bionic:~# apt policy qt5-default
qt5-default:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
root@bionic:~#
```

1. First, you launch the container from **ubuntu:18.04**. In this case it would be OK to also use **images:ubuntu/18.04**, however for some other tasks it is better to stick to **ubuntu:18.04**.
2. Second, when you get a shell in the container, you need to run **apt update** so that the package list is updated. I suppose this was the issue; you did not run this command, therefore the container did not have any list of packages. The containers with Ubuntu perform a daily check for security updates, therefore, if you had left the container running for a day, then it would have ran **apt update** by itself. However it is good practice to run **apt update** when you first create the container. There is also a way to configure LXD to make the container to auto-update as soon as they are created.
3. **apt policy qt5-default** shows that the package is available, from the *universe* repository.